# Generic way of error handling in Angular using interceptors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using Angular 1.08, hence I need to use `responseInterceptors`.

First the code.

Interpreter:

```
app.factory('errorInterceptor', ['$q', 'NotificationService', function ($q, NotificationService) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            // do something on success
            return response;
        }, function (response) {
            // do something on error
            alert('whoops.. error');
            NotificationService.setError("Error occured!");

            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    }
}]);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
});
```

NotificationService:

```
app.service("NotificationService", function () {
    var error = '';

    this.setError = function (value) {
        error = value;
    }

    this.getError = function () {
        return error;
    }

    this.hasError = function () {
        return error.length > 0;
    }
});
```

Directive error-box:

```
app.directive("errorBox", function (NotificationService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div data-ng-show="hasError">{{ errorMessage }}</div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$watch(NotificationService.getError, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal != oldVal) {
                    scope.errorMessage = newVal;
                    scope.hasError = NotificationService.hasError();
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

The problem: When I use `<error-box>` at multiple places, all these boxes will display the error message. This is not my intent. I'd like to show only the error-box where the exception occurs.

For example, I have a directive which shows a list of transactions. When fetching the transactions fails, I want to show the error-box which is declared in that part.
I also have a directive where I can edit a customer. This directive also contains the error-box tag.

What happens is when saving a customer fails, both error-boxes are displayed, however, I only want the error-box of the customer to be displayed.

Does someone has an idea to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular services are Singleton objects, as described in the angular docs [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services).  This means that Angular only creates one single "global" instance of a service and uses that same instance whenever the given service is requested.  That means that Angular only ever creates one single instance of your `NotificationService` services and then will supply that one instance to every instance of your `errorBox` directive.  So if one directive updates the `NotificationService`'s error value, then all of the `<error-box` directives will get that value.

So, you're going to have to either create multiple notification services for each type of error (ie `TransactionNotification` and `CustomerNotification`, etc) or add different methods to your main `NotificationService` that would allow you to set only specific alerts (such as `NotificationService.setCustomerError()` or `NotificationService.setTransactionError()`).

None of those options are particularly user-friendly nor clean, but I believe (given the way you've set up your service), that's the only way to do it.

UPDATE: After thinking about it, I might suggest just dropping your whole `NotificationService` class and just using `$scope` events to notify your `<error-box>` elements when an error occurs:

In your `'errorInterceptor'`:

```
app.factory('errorInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            // do something on success
            return response;
        }, function (response) {
            // do something on error
            alert('whoops.. error');
            var errorType = ...; // do something to determine the type of error
            switch(errorType){
                case 'TransactionError':
                    $rootScope.$emit('transaction-error', 'An error occurred!');
                    break;
                case 'CustomerError':
                    $rootScope.$emit('customer-error', 'An error occurred!');
                    break;
                ...
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    }
}]);
```

And then in your `errorBox` directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var typeOfError = attrs.errorType;
        scope.$on(typeOfError, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal != oldVal) {
                scope.errorMessage = newVal;
            }
        });

    }
```

And then in your view:

```
<error-box error-type="transaction-error"></error-box>
<error-box error-type="customer-error"></error-box>
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. This gives me definitely something to think about.